# Delete Azure Active Directory (ADD) & Associated Portal

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I recently started looking at my Azure Subscription again.  A long time ago, I was playing with Azure Active Directory...and created 2 of them.

Let's just call them...

- AAA Directory
- BBB Directory

Apparently, Azure creates a completely separate 'portal' alongside each manually created 'active directory'.  I wanted to delete them...so I went to DELETE & followed the instructions

- I deleted all groups
- I deleted all application registrations
- I deleted all users
- I have no subscriptions...but somehow...it 'thinks' I do...and shows "Delete all license-based subscriptions"

Choosing the "Delete all license-based subscriptions" link brings you to a page that says you need to go to the 'Azure Admin Center'...

- Clicking DELETE in the 'Azure Admin Center' dashboard shows the "You can't delete the last dashboard" error message

I feel like I am going in circles.

- How do I delete each of the manually created Azure AD's entirely?
- How do I delete any associated portals to the manually created AD's entirely?
- How do I get the manually created AD Portal's 'directories' to stop listing in my subscription tab?

**UPDATE:**
I have noticed the following message:

"We have detected that your current user account is external to this tenant. Please sign-out and login with Global Admin credentials using the initial default domain name such as user@contoso.onmicrosoft.com."

- But my Microsoft Account lists as being a Global Admin

[image]

Comment: Did you check these? "you may have also activated license-based subscriptions for your organization like Azure AD Premium P2, Office 365 Business Premium, or Enterprise Mobility + Security E5... The subscriptions must be in a Deprovisioned state to allow directory deletion. An Expired or Canceled subscription moves to the Disabled state, and the final stage is the Deprovisioned state." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-delete-howto#if-you-cant-delete-the-directory

Comment: From portal.azure.com - I used the "switch directory" option...from "home"...I went into "subscriptions"...and nothing is there.  So...I don't get it.

Comment: From "aad.portal.azure.com" - I looked in "Licenses"...and none exist...I chose "Self-Service Sign Up Products"...and none exist

Comment: From "aad.portal.azure.com" - my Microsoft Account is "Global Administrator" for each of the AD's

Comment: @AlexAIT I didn't add-or-activate license-based subscription. In fact, I don't own any...so...unless that has been somehow added FOR me...they do not exist.

Comment: I created and deleted a directory just to test if everything works - seemed fine. I would suggest you go the route of a "free support request" via https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/community/ somebody will probably take the time to look into your issue.

Comment: @AlexAIT Thanks for doing that...